# Is there an unzipped Ubuntu 11.10 available for download?

Tags: 11.10

I've tried two decompressors: ADL and Universal, and they both say the Ubuntu 11.10-desktop.iso is corrupt.

I'd like to bypass this step and install on my 4Gb flash drive.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to decompress the .ISO file to install it on a USB drive. 
Go to this web site and download the USB pendrive installer 
[USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

[image]

You did not say if you were using Windows or not. This little guy should do the trick.